# How to calculate $I= {\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{dt}{z-e^{it}}} \,(z\in \mathbb{C}, |z|>1)$ using Riemann sums?

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

I came to study the Riemann sums and face to the following exercise. I have got no idea about how to solve it:

> $I= {\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{dt}{z-e^{it}}} \quad (z\in \mathbb{C}, |z|>1)$

Do you have any clues to start?

Comment: Looks like the complex analysis tag is more suiting here.

Comment: And are you saying that you are supposed to solve this with Riemann sums?  It certainly doesn't look like a problem where Riemann sums would be the recommended approach.

Comment: Yes, I am, I must solve this with Riemann sums

Comment: Write $I=\frac{1}{z}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{dt}{1+e^{it}/z}=\frac{1}{z}\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{1}{z^n}\int_{0}^{2\pi}(-1)^ne^{int}dt=\frac{1}{z}\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{1}{z^n}\int_{0}^{2\pi}(-1)^n(\cos(nt)+i\sin(nt))dt$. So, you only need to compute the integrals of $\cos(nt)$ and $\sin(nt)$ on $[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: ok, thank you very mush

Comment: Is *Cauchy Integral Formula* out of the question?

Comment: @Jack One of my profs used to do things like: solve this exercise using (A) method 1 and (B) method 2 to make the students really appreciate how much superior one method can be over the other in certain situations.

Comment: Only the Riemann sums

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To simplify a little, put $J=\int_0^1\frac{dt}{z-\exp(2i\pi t)}$. Then your integral is $2\pi J$.

The Riemann sum to consider is 
 $$S_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{z-\exp(2i\pi k/n)}$$
 Let $P(z)=z^n-1=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(z-\exp(2i\pi k/n))$. Then we have 
 $$\frac{P^{\prime}(z)}{P(z)}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{z-\exp(2i\pi k/n)}=nS_n$$

It is now easy to find the limit of $S_n$.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I might be back later for further informations.